# Overloaded functions in modules

Tags: f#, overloading

Since curried functions cannot be overloaded and modules cannot have members, does this mean there is no way to have an overloaded function in a module? The answer seems obvious, but I want to make sure there's not something I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, no overloaded functions in modules (more generally, no way to overload a let-bound function).  If you say `f`, then `f` always has a single type, whereas if you say `o.f`, that may refer to a group of overloads (resolved by surrounding context).